# JAVA How to find the highest number in each row of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have made it find the max and min value in the entire 2d array seen below but now I'm wanting to make it find the highest value in each row and don't really know how to go about it.

```
public class Main
{

  public static void main ( String[] args )  
  {
    int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
                     {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
                     {9, 1, 0, 2},
                     {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };

    
    int max = data[0][0];
    int min = data[0][0];
  
    
    for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++)
    {
      for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++) 
      {
         if (data[row][col] > max){
           max = data[row][col];
           
         }
         if (data[row][col] < min){
           min = data[row][col];
         }
      }
    }  

    System.out.println( "max = " + max + "; min = " + min );

  }
}
```

I keep getting results like

```
2
5
4
4
8
1
3
1
1
2
2
6
6
6
6
```

Comment: *I keep getting results like...* Not from what you posted. There's nothing wrong with it

Comment: Since there's one min per row, you are going to need an array for the min values.  Same thing with max.  You will want to initialize mins[i] inside the outer loop.

Comment: Oh I see. So your code is not wrong *per se* but if your goal is that you want the min/max *of each row* then you *will* need to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will print the `max` and `min` for each `row`

```
for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++)
{
  for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++) 
  {
     //Find max as usual
     if (data[row][col] > max){
       max = data[row][col];
     }
     
     //Find min as usual
     if (data[row][col] < min){
       min = data[row][col];
     }
  }
  
  //Print min/max for this row
  System.out.println("row = " + row + "; max = " + max + "; min = " + min );
  
  //Reset min/max
  max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

If you'd like to still find the overall `max`/`min`, instead of printing the values, add them to an array and find the `max`/`min` from there

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int min(int[][] data) {
    return calcRowMinMax(minPerRow(data), true);
}

public static int max(int[][] data) {
    return calcRowMinMax(maxPerRow(data), false);
}

public static int[] minPerRow(int[][] data) {
    int[] min = new int[data.length];

    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++)
        min[row] = calcRowMinMax(data[row], true);

    return min;
}

public static int[] maxPerRow(int[][] data) {
    int[] max = new int[data.length];

    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++)
        max[row] = calcRowMinMax(data[row], false);

    return max;
}

private static int calcRowMinMax(int[] row, boolean min) {
    int res = min ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int val : row)
        res = min ? Math.min(res, val) : Math.max(res, val);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `minPerRow()` returns all `Integer.MIN_VALUE`s. `maxPerRow()` returns all `Integer.MAX_VALUE`s.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without plain for loops using built-in classes

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] data = { {3, 2, 5},
            {1, 4, 4, 8, 13},
            {9, 1, 0, 2},
            {0, 2, 6, 3, -1, -8} };
        var statistics = Stream.of(data).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).summaryStatistics();
        int min = statistics.getMin(), max = statistics.getMax();
    }
```

**Edit**: I was inattentive. Below is an example of getting the maximum value in a particular row. If you want to process all data, you should iterate over `allStatistics`

```
        //data allocation
        var allStatistics = Stream.of(data)
           .map(row -> IntStream.of(row).summaryStatistics())
           .toList();
        int maxOfSecondRow = allStatistics.get(1).getMax();
```

Comment: The OP already has that solution (which is not the one he wants)